# Compare two columns, one by float and other by strings to get matching values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, string-comparison

I have two dataframes with two of its columns that really matter. One of the column consists of float64 values and the other is string.
the dataframes are of different sizes.

I would like to match both the `Number` column and the `Item` column at the same time and then get only the ones that match.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({ 'Number':[1.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,8.0,12.0,32.0,58.0] , 'Item': ['Phone', 'Watch', 'Pen', 'Pencil', 'Pencil','toolkit','box','fork']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Number':[3.0,4.0,8.0,12.0,15.0,32.0,54.0,58.0,72.0], 'Item':['Watch','Pen','Pencil','Eraser','bottle','box','toolkit','fork','Phone']})

df1
Number     Item
0     1.0    Phone
1     3.0    Watch
2     4.0      Pen
3     5.0   Pencil
4     8.0   Pencil
5    12.0  toolkit
6    32.0      box
7    58.0     fork

df2
   Number     Item
0     3.0    Watch
1     4.0      Pen
2     8.0   Pencil
3    12.0   Eraser
4    15.0   bottle
5    32.0      box
6    54.0  toolkit
7    58.0     fork
8    72.0    Phone
```

I am trying to use forloop and the loop goes very long. It seems to be very bad method of achieving this. I am trying to use mask operation but unsure how to achieve this. Appreciate help in performing this in the shortest way possible.

The desired result should look like:

```
      Item  Matching  Number
0    Phone  No Match     1.0
1    Watch   Matched     3.0
2      Pen   Matched     4.0
3   Pencil  No Match     5.0
4   Pencil   Matched     8.0
5  toolkit  No Match    12.0
6      box   Matched    32.0
7     fork   Matched    58.0
```

Comment: Show the expected output

Comment: @SreeramTP the answer must look something like this. df1 = pd.DataFrame({ 'Number':[1.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,8.0,12.0,32.0,58.0] , 'Item': ['Phone', 'Watch', 'Pen', 'Pencil', 'Pencil','toolkit','box','fork'], 'Matching':['No Match', 'Matched', 'Matched', 'No Match', 'Matched', 'Matched', 'Matched', 'Matched']})

Comment: @Sudhi, Note in your desired result tookit -12.0 should *not* be matched.

Comment: @jpp You are correct. Sorry that was a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can come to the dataframe you need by some simple `loc` and `isin` as shown below

```
df = df1.copy()

df['Matching'] = np.nan
df.loc[(df.Number.isin(df2.Number)) & (df.Item.isin(df2.Item)), 'Matching'] = 'Matched'
df.Matching.fillna('No Match', inplace=True)

Number    Item      Matching

1.0   Phone     No Match
3.0   Watch     Matched
4.0   Pen       Matched
5.0   Pencil    No Match
8.0   Pencil    Matched
12.0  toolkit   Matched
32.0  box       Matched
58.0  fork      Matched
```

Comment: Very great solution. Less code and works fast. My original dataset has a shape (3388, 35). It takes just 0.009244 seconds to complete the compare. both your solution and jezrael's solution works well for me

Comment: You can simply check output by `print (df.Matching.value_counts())`

Comment: @jezrael I see what you're saying. In the sample data I see that the number 12.0 shows as matched, where as in reality it is not. In my real data set. since it is large, I need sometime to double check if there is any mistake. Will get back. Thanks for highlighting this.

Comment: @jezrael I didn't get you. The output is same as the sample output shown in the comments

Comment: @SreeramTP - OK, there was typo, but still solution is wrong. I try change data

Comment: @SreeramTP - be free test `np.random.seed(456)

L = ['Phone', 'Watch', 'Pen', 'Pencil', 'toolkit','box','fork']
df1 = pd.DataFrame({ 'Number':np.random.randint(5, size=20) , 
                    'Item': np.random.choice(L, size=20)})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Number':np.random.randint(5, size=10), 
                    'Item': np.random.choice(L, size=10)})
`

Comment: I don't think this answer is right. Why is 12.0 - toolkit marked as `Matched` when it's *not* a common row? You are tested each series separately which, I believe, is not what OP wants.

Comment: I have only tested the code with tje data provided in the question, which is my mistake. If he can un accept the answer I am ready to delete it

Comment: Hi All, pls allow me time till tomorrow. I shall validate and get back on this so we can finalize which answer is correct. Thank you all for contributing.

Comment: @SreeramTP. Your logic works accurately for my actual data. So I will keep this as the correct answer. Thank you once again

Answer (score 3):

If problem merge float values, is possible multiple by `1000` and cast to integers and then [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) with left join, because there should be problem with matching, baciuse float precision should be different in both columns:

```
df1['Number1'] = df1['Number'].mul(1000).astype(int)
df2['Number1'] = df2['Number'].mul(1000).astype(int)

df = pd.merge(df1, df2.drop('Number', 1), how='left', on=['Item','Number1'], indicator=True)
df['Matching'] = df['_merge'].map({'left_only':'No Match', 'both':'Match'})

df = df.drop(['Number1','_merge'], axis=1)
print (df)

   Number     Item  Matching
0     1.0    Phone  No Match
1     3.0    Watch     Match
2     4.0      Pen     Match
3     5.0   Pencil  No Match
4     8.0   Pencil     Match
5    12.0  toolkit  No Match
6    32.0      box     Match
7    58.0     fork     Match
```

Comment: Your solution seems to combine both the df1 and df2 dataset. This is also a good solution for my requirement. My original dataset has a shape (3388, 35). Your logic takes 0.112811 seconds to complete. This is also cool. I need to mark one of them as the right.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for a left merge with `indicator=True`:

```
res = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', indicator=True)

print(res)

      Item  Number     _merge
0    Phone     1.0  left_only
1    Watch     3.0       both
2      Pen     4.0       both
3   Pencil     5.0  left_only
4   Pencil     8.0       both
5  toolkit    12.0  left_only
6      box    32.0       both
7     fork    58.0       both
```

In general, avoid explicit `for` loops when purpose-built methods are available, as these are generally optimized for performance. You can, if you wish, then replace strings via a dictionary mapping:

```
d = {'left_only': 'No Match', 'both': 'Matched'}
df['_merge'] = df['_merge'].map(d)
```